# Ubuntu Core V/S ROS

Tags: ubuntu-core, ros

What is the difference between ROS and UBUNTU CORE??? 
I am very much confused betwwen ROS and Ubuntu core. 
Is ros an app for ubuntu core?

Answer (score 3):

Straight from [the ROS wesite](http://www.ros.org/about-ros/):

> The Robot Operating System (ROS) is a flexible framework for writing robot software. It is a collection of tools, libraries, and conventions that aim to simplify the task of creating complex and robust robot behavior across a wide variety of robotic platforms.

[Uuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/core):

> Ubuntu Core is a tiny, transactional version of Ubuntu for IoT devices and large container deployments. It runs a new breed of super-secure, remotely upgradeable Linux app packages known as snaps ‐ and it’s trusted by leading IoT players, from chipset vendors to device makers and system integrators.

__

ROS is a framework of applications for Linux to control external hardware, specifically robots. Ubuntu Core is just a lightweight version of Ubuntu that uses the Snap packaging system, meant to run on low-power devices.

ROS needs an OS to work. Ubuntu Core is just that: a core.

---

This comes from 2 minutes of using Google, by the way. It's usually less effort to just look something up than sign up for a website.